# Mingw failing when building my project in Release mode

Tags: c++, windows, qt, gcc, mingw

When running my Qt Project on windows (gcc.exe (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0) in Release mode, I am getting the error:

`Mingw-w64 runtime failure: 32 bit pseudo relocation at 00007FF7B06A3490 out of range, targeting 00007FFAEA8D17C0, yielding the value 000000033A22E32C.`

Running it in Debug or even in minimum size release mode works fine.
Does anyone have an idea, why this might be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: see https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/10547

Comment: GCC 6.3 is old (from 2016). Please consider a newer compiler, and use MinGW-w64 instead of MinGW.
Standalone Windows binaries available from https://winlibs.com/